# Secure boot while still being able to keep up with nightlies

Tags: boot, disk-encryption

Following [this great answer](https://j.mp/SARI1A), I've secured the bootloader on my Nexus 7 deb by using `fastboot oem lock` and installing the original Google-provided recovery image.

However, I now have a dilemma. Here's my setup:

1. My device is encrypted with a very strong passphrase.
2. I'm running a CyanogenMod nightly, but I'm planning on sticking to more stable releases as they become available. (The nightly which I'm running is because it provides keyboard layouts as imported from AOSP that were previously unavailable)

Every so often, I'll get a crash and the device will reboot itself, there are weirdness with Bluetooth, etc. This I have accepted with running nightlies, I know what I'm getting myself into.

I just realized the terrifying truth: in order for me to `fastboot oem unlock` my device, a user data wipe is necessary. That really, really stinks.

Is there a way for me to do this without wiping my data? Moving forward, is there a way for me to both maintain security of my device and be able to flash new updates to my ROM?